# Is it possible to make a string date comparision inside the mongo $filter cond operator?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate, mongodate

In this case, to fetch more compact data from MongoDB, I need to filter subdocument (`records`) by date value that has a string type. As you can see below, the `record` document is a nested array.

```
[
{
    "_id": 14,
    "isActive": true,
    "name": "D.HONGKONG-1",
    "factory_id": 10,
    "factory_name": "CHAOI",
    "branches":
    {
        "_id": 205,
        "isActive": true,
        "name": "DZZ NUCE",
        "region_id": 14,
        "owner_name": "A",
        "phone": "",
        "records": [
        {
            "date": "24-10-2020",
            "sales": [
            {
                "time": "17:58",
                "explanation": "DAILY CALCULATION",
                "type": "DAILY",
                "quantity":
                {
                    "P": 0,
                    "K": 0,
                    "U": 0
                }
            }],
            "stocks": [
            {
                "time": "17:58",
                "explanation": "DELIVERY COMPL",
                "type": "DELIVERY",
                "quantity":
                {
                    "P": 0,
                    "K": 0,
                    "U": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "time": "17:58",
                "explanation": "DAILY S. ENTRY",
                "type": "DAILY",
                "quantity":
                {
                    "P": 0,
                    "K": 0,
                    "U": 0
                }
            }],
            "delivery":
            {
                "P": 0,
                "K": 0,
                "U": 0
            },
            "material": []
        },
        {
            "date": "23-10-2020",
            "sales": [
            {
                "time": "17:58",
                "explanation": "",
                "type": "DAILY",
                "quantity":
                {
                    "P": 0,
                    "K": 0,
                    "U": 0
                }
            }],
            "stocks": [
            {
                "time": "17:58",
                "explanation": "",
                "type": "DELIVERY",
                "quantity":
                {
                    "P": 0,
                    "K": 0,
                    "U": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "time": "17:58",
                "explanation": "",
                "type": "DAILY",
                "quantity":
                {
                    "P": 0,
                    "K": 0,
                    "U": 0
                }
            }],
            "delivery":
            {
                "P": 0,
                "K": 0,
                "U": 0
            },
            "material": []
        }]
    }
}]
```

When I try to achieve this goal by using the script below, I have encountered some issues listed below.

- ConversionFailure (code:241):
  I think `$dateFromString` couldn't consume `"$$record.date"` filter value. It is working when I use it without `$dateFromString`.
- LocationError (code:31261):
  While using the `$function` to compare dates, the `cond` argument of `$function` throws an error like this. So, I couldn't use a function too.

```
        aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    factory_id: parseInt(factoryId),
                    isActive: true
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'branches',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'region_id',
                    as: 'branches',
                },
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$branches'
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    name: 1,
                    factory_id: 1,
                    factory_name: 1,
                    isActive: 1,
                    // 'order': 1,
                    'branches._id': 1,
                    'branches.name': 1,
                    'branches.isActive': 1,
                    'branches.region_id': 1,
                    'branches.owner_name': 1,
                    'branches.phone': 1,
                    'branches.records': {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$branches.records',
                            as: 'record',
                            cond: {

                                $eq: [{
                                        $dateFromString: {
                                            dateString: "11-11-2021",
                                            format: "%d-%m-%Y"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $dateFromString: {
                                            dateString: "$$record.date",
                                            format: "%d-%m-%Y"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

I really didn't find a solution to compare these dates inside `$filter cond` to complete my requirement. What are the possible solutions? Thanks

Comment: In general, your syntax for `$filter` and its condition looks okay. Can you post a sample document that is output from the `$unwind` stage? Also, tell about the MongoDB version.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. Postman JSON response here. My collection has tones of data, I tried to reduce them. I hope this is enough to review. (It contains some bad data too, but it won't affect you) https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuXa7KvcCIe5m7Fy1foZrmjg7AWjZQ?e=gdkR3N

Comment: I am not able to open it. Paste in this: https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: (I could open the link in another browser). As I had mentioned earlier comment, the filter and its condition looks fine for the posted data - I looked up one document. Are there data with bad strings, nulls, different types, etc., you need to check. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I stated the errors above, If I use the `$dateFromString` I got ConversionFailure, and If I try to use `$function`, it throws a LocationError. I think the problem is about passing reference value to a method as a parameter, probably it is not allowed. I also tried `{ $convert: { input: "$$record.date", to: "date" } }` in `$filter cond{}` but it is not working too. Actually, I didn't find a method to convert a string to date and to compare it with another value. Maybe I m in the wrong way.

Comment: `I got ConversionFailure` - please post the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem myself. It may be a workaround but it works now.
In the `$filter` operator `cond` attribute needs the same date object to compare. However, the parsing is impossible for `$filter` reference values, due to the methods weren't able to read them. So at this point, to do this, we need to use the `$convert` operator as below.

```
cond: {
    $gte: [{
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: lastDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
                format: '%d-%m-%Y',
            },
        },
        {
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: {
                    $convert: {
                        input: '$$record.date',
                        to: 'string',
                    },
                },
                format: '%d-%m-%Y',
            },
        },
    ]
}
```